# debian LTS : how to keep packages up-to-date with last security fixes using apt

Tags: debian, apt, package-management

What's the best way to keep packages up-to-date (ie with the last security fixes) without worried about major version update ?

For instance, apache2 for squeezeis is  2.2.16 (https://packages.debian.org/source/squeeze/apache2)

However, last apache2 version for the 2.2.x branch is 2.2.27

Test repository can't be used since they use the 2.4.x versions and I'd like to stick on the 2.2.x (to avoid migration issues)

How would you handle this situation and how can I update to 2.2.27 ?

Comment: You understand that generally people backport security fixes right?  Looking at only the version number is often meaningless.

Comment: So you are saying that package are up to date with security backport and different version names ? However some package don't seem up do date at all (ie last tomcat6 security fix is from 2013 - http://metadata.ftp-master.debian.org/changelogs//main/t/tomcat6/tomcat6_6.0.35-1+squeeze4_changelog)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually just upgrading your packages from native repositories should be enough provided you have *security.debian.org* repository enabled in `/etc/apt/sources.list`.

At the moment limited "LTS" support is only available for previous ("oldstable") Debian release codename "squeeze". Read the following page for instructions how to configure your system to pull LTS updates:

- https://wiki.debian.org/LTS

From security prospective it is always better to use current [Debian release](https://www.debian.org/releases/) a.k.a. "stable" which perhaps will be better supported than "LTS".

Read more:

- https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/securing-debian-howto/ch4.en.html
- https://security-tracker.debian.org/tracker/
- https://www.debian.org/security/

Comment: I'm a bit lost with the security repository, security updates aren't included in the https://packages.debian.org/squeeze ? So only bug-fixes are included in this repository ?

Comment: High priority security fixes (only) are shipped through "security.debian.org". Bug and security fixes are shipped through other repositories.
See https://wiki.debian.org/SourcesList and check example "sources.list".